# Assign data to a child list of another List in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have 2 Classes lets say ParentClass and ChildClass

```
public class ParentClass 
{
   public int Property1 {get; set;}
   public List<Child> {get; set;}
}

public class ChildClass
{
   public int Property1 {get; set;}
   public string Property2 {get; set;}
}
```

Now i have an object of parent class

```
// in my case all data has been assign to parent object properties except List<ChildClass>
List<ParentClass > parent = data
```

How can i assign data to List property of parent list without using Loop.

Thanks

Comment: Whats wrong with loop? Linq is for *querying* - loop if good for modifying

Comment: is loop the only option? i was just looking for the best possible solution. i was previously using automapper but as CraeteMap method of Automapper is not  threadsafe, it was returning data of only first queried item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) (Language-Integrated Query) is for *querying*. And querying is a thing which does not supposed to cause side-effects. Modifying objects is a pure side-effect. So, Linq is just inappropriate tool here. Even more - internally LINQ uses loops, so there will not be any performance benefit also.

Suggestion - use simple loop to update your objects - its very simple construct which is easy to understand:

```
foreach(var parent in parents)
   parent.Children = GetChildren(parent.Id);
```

Without explicit loop you can use [`List.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
parents.ForEach(p => p.Children = GetChildren(parent.Id));
```

But I don't like this approach - why write something that looks like foreach, if you can use foreach? Also introducing lambda adds complexity to your system.

---

> but as CreateMap method of Automapper is not threadsafe

With Automapper you usually create maps on application startup (`Main` method on Winforms, or `Global.asax` on web - both are executed on single thread). Also you always can wrap maps creation with `lock` statement, as with any other code which needs thread synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot really understand what you want to do.

Maybe,

```
var parent = data.Select(p => new ParentClass{Property1 = p.Property1}).ToList();
```

You'll get copy of data, but List<Child> property will not be copied.

Comment: I have 2 lists  List<ParentClass> and List<ChildClass>, List<ChildClass> is also a member of ParentClass, so how can i assign data to that member of ParentClass

Comment: What type has data variable?
List<Child>?

What is the name of that?

Comment: No, its List<ParentClass>. i just mentioned here for example. List<Parent> parent = //select data from database it has all members except Data for List<ChildClass> member. i have another query where i ma selecting List<ChildClass>, now i want to assign data to ParentClass memeber List<ChildClass>. I know we can loop through List<ParentClass> and assign value to each item of list but i just want to know if there is any other option.

Comment: Oh, now I understand, Sergey Berezovskiy is absolutely right, "Linq is for querying - loop if good for modifying". Or, you can use ForEach method, if you want. Anyway, loop should be used in such situation.